# На какой уровень рассчитаны наши ответы?

Tags: обсуждение

Мне кажется, что наши ответы рассчитаны **на школьный уровень,** хотя сообщество  называется "Cайт вопросов и ответов **для лингвистов** и энтузиастов русского языка".

Собственно говоря, вопрос заключается в следующем: **почему у нас последнее время всё нешкольное, нестандартное, альтернативное безжалостно уничтожается, отрицается и подвергается гонениям?** И это даже в том случае, если границы обозначены: это базовый вариант, а это чуть повыше уровнем.

**Вот участник Niemand по своему усмотрению расставляет оценки за ответ:** "Нет, лучше умствовать на пустом месте и из-за этого делать ошибки, за которые и в школе **двойки** ставят. Разумеется, обособление необходимо, отсутствие – грубая ошибка, за которую школьникам не **четверку**, а сразу **трояк** надо ставить". **Ну чем не школа?**

**Вот участник Римма Михайлова  критикует П. Капицу:** " А предложения тридцатых-пятидесятых годов? Я бы и в них поставила запятые". Но до 1956 года **образованные люди ставили знаки препинания по уму и сердцу** (и кстати, по любви к русскому языку), а не по готовым правилам, написанным для нас Розенталем. Хотя бы поэтому я не стала бы пренебрежительно относиться к их записям.

**Школьный уровень знаний – это лучше, чем  никакой:** всё-таки люди знают правила, а не ставят запятые наугад. Но язык развивается, появляются новые слова, другая грамматика.  **И люди становятся умнее, образованнее** (хотелось бы так думать), они больше пишут, ищут новые формы, которых еще нет в правилах.

Да и правила всегда имеют ограничения в своем применении, особенно если ты **не школьник, а ученый или писатель с мировым именем,** для которого главное – это не следовать в точности правилам, а как можно точнее выразить свою мысль.

И к правилам можно относиться по-разному: для кого-то запятые – **это просто оформительские значки, а для кого-то они обозначают ритмику русской речи.** Конечно, формальное отношение у нас в приоритете, но почему бы не учитывать интересы и другой стороны.

Вот, к примеру,  **Набокову** потребовалось обозначить знаками пунктуации прерванную речь. Еще чего выдумал, заклеймить его позором! Стиль речи хотите обозначить? Это лишнее: чем проще, тем лучше. Минус за ответ.

Казалось бы, каждая точка зрения должна быть учтена, **качественный ответ – это ответ обоснованный, содержащий новую информацию и не копирующий содержание уже данных ответов.** Чем больше мнений, тем содержательнее форум, пусть автор вопроса выберет то, что ему по душе.

Но некоторые участники больше "внимания" уделяют критике чужих ответов, чем качеству своих собственных. **И очень ревностно следят за тем, чтобы средний (школьный)  уровень никаким образом не был превышен.**

Comment: > И к правилам можно относиться по-разному: для кого-то запятые – это просто оформительские значки, а для кого-то они обозначают ритмику русской речи. Конечно, формальное отношение у нас в приоритете, но почему бы не учитывать интересы и другой стороны. "Другая сторона" - это вы? И в чем ваш интерес?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что здесь уместна фраза: "чтобы нарушать правила, нужно их знать". Матёрый автор уровня Набокова, сознательно решивший нарушить правило, не нуждается в том, чтобы ему это разрешили незнакомые люди на форуме русского языка. Сюда обращаются именно с вопросом "как правильно?", когда сомневаются.

Нет ничего удивительного в том, что форум забит "школьными" вопросами, ведь как раз в школе проходят практически всю грамматическую базу, а за её пределы лезть случайному человеку вряд ли часто приходится.

Однако я полагаю, никто не будет возражать, если кто-то организует на форуме тему о том, каким, например, может стать наш язык, если ввести в него ещё два рода, помимо существующих. Вот вам и передовой лингвистический вопрос. Только что тут обсуждать? У вас либо есть представление о том, как это должно выглядеть, либо этого представления нет. Это уже будет скорее желание похвастаться своей фантазией, чем вопрос к специалистам, потому что им ответить ровным счётом нечего, кроме: "Такого в учебниках нет". Конечно, нет. Вы и сами это знаете.

Поэтому форум и работает с той базой, которую реально обсудить предметно.

Что касается меня, я всегда в ответах, где это уместно, обращаю внимание человека, который спрашивает, что, по правилам, нужно писать вот так вот. Но также я добавляю, что, если человек пишет какой-то художественный экспериментальный текст, то он свободен в своих решениях.

Однако я всё же против идеи "куда захотел, туда запятую и поставил". Чушь это всё. Для любого отхождения от правил нужна объективная причина. А чисто интуитивные запятые, которые не прописаны в правилах, для меня остаются лишь признаком лени автора, не захотевшего проверять.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. За три года многое изменилось...

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень понимаю, в чем суть вопроса, но ответы на нашем сайте должны быть полезными и понятными. Их "уровень" неважен. Можно объяснить все на пальцах, не применяя терминов и не давая ссылок на академическую грамматику. Можно же использовать цитаты из справочников, объяснять сложные грамматические явления. Всё, однако, будет приемлемо.